# Angular JS: get ng-model on ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="c.name for c in countries" ng-change="filterByCountry"></select>
```

That is beeing fed by the following object with a list of countries

```
$scope.countries = [{name:Afeganistão, country:AF}, {name:África do Sul, country:ZA}, name:Albânia, country:AL}, {name:Alemanha, country:DE}, {name:Andorra, country:AD} ...];
```

When I change my dropdown value I was expecting my model ($scope.country) to be updated, inside filterByCountry function, but it isn't. What am I missing here?

Comment: doesn't ng-change need parenthesis `ng-change="filterByCountry()"` then just access $scope.country in the method.

Comment: Exactly that seems to be the issue... http://jsbin.com/paguwehu/2/

Comment: I forgot the parenthesis when creating here the question, but that is not the issue here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ng-change` handler is fired before the `ng-model` is actually updated. If you want `filterByCountry` to be fired every time `$scope.country` changes (rather than just when the dropdown changes), you should use the following instead:

```
$scope.$watch('country', filterByCountry);
```

I always find it more useful to react to changes in my `$scope` rather than DOM events when possible.

Comment: I already tried your solution but watch is not beeing triggered when changing dropdown value :S

Comment: @JoaoAlmeida - Do you have a Fiddle or anything?

Comment: Your answer was right (despite I tried that solution before asking the question). My problem was that I was using ng-if for showing that dropdown. I change for ng-show and now works fine. Thanks ;)

Comment: @JustinNiessner, that is incorrect. `ng-change` is fired after `ng-model` is updated: http://plnkr.co/edit/JgvNTTJWAq2hSkzky6nu?p=preview . In fact, adding `$watch` is unnecessarily expensive if you intend to only react to user-initiated changes

Comment: @NewDev - That may be the case now (I haven't checked on the latest versions of Angular), but wasn't at the time this question was asked. And reacting only to user-initiated changes (whether at an added cost or not) breaks two-way data-binding and will inevitably lead to issues later on if the application is anything except a very basic one.

Comment: @JustinNiessner, I provided a link with Angular v1.2.0, which was available at that time. And I'm not at all understanding what you mean by "breaks two-way data-binding" - how does that break it? `ng-change` is a directive [built to work](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1281) in tandem with `ng-model`.

Comment: @NewDev - First of all, you may have provided a link for 1.2 but, as far as I know, they hadn't implemented priority yet so, while your example way work, it's not guaranteed. Second, it breaks two-way binding because you're no longer reacting to changes in the data but rather user input. If something else were to modify `country`, `filterByCountry` wouldn't be run and the UI would be in an incorrect state. By using `$scope.$watch`, you can guarantee that no matter what changes `country`, the filter is always executed properly.

Answer (score 11):

Just for anyone else coming here,
`ng-change` is actually called *after* the model value has been set.

**Why?**
Let's see when is it called.
From the [angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngChange.js#L70), `ng-change` is just an attribute directive with this directive definition object (DDO).

```
{
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
        scope.$eval(attr.ngChange);
      });
    }
}
```

From this we see that the `ng-change` directive is very simple. All that `ng-change='<expr>'` does is add a function to the end of `$viewChangeListeners` that evaluates `<expr>` via [$scope.$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval).

*OK ... so when are the ViewChangeListeners called?*

Well, if we look at the documentation for [ngModel.NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController):

> the new value will be applied to $modelValue and then the expression specified in the ng-model attribute. **Lastly, all the registered change listeners, in the $viewChangeListeners list, are called**.

So the viewChangeListener for the ngChange will be invoked *after* the value is applied to `$modelValue`. Hence the callback will be invoked *after* the model as been set.

*Also note that this behavior is the same in all versions of angular. The definition for `ng-change` hasn't changed since v1.2.*

Comment: Now why am I seeing the opposite behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As **James Lawson** pointed,

> ng-change is actually called after the model value has been set.

And if you still asking

> Now why am I seeing the opposite behavior?

Then you should know that the *$scope* is prototypical inherited from its parent, and if your scope variable is just a simple type (string, boolean, etc..) then it will be overwritten in child scope to value that was set by *ng-model* directive

To see where the child scope is created (on what DOM element) you can open *dev tools* and look for `class="ng-scope"` on element