# Angular - ngChange triggers before ngModel for <select>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669400/angular-js-get-ng-model-on-ng-change) related topic, where the answer suggests to watch for the model change instead of the change of the select. But in my example the "model" is part of an object inside a list. Is the correct way to initialize `$watch`for every object in the list?

**Select**

```
 <li data-ng-repeat="obj in main.list track by $index">
    <select data-ng-change="main.changeStatus(obj)" data-ng-model="obj.status">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
 </li>
```

**changeStatus**

I need to update the object or already receive the correct object in the change method.

```
main.changeStatus = function(obj) {
  var r = new Resource(obj);
  ...
  r.$save({...}, function (savedObj) {
    ...
  });
}
```

What's the correct way to solve this issue?

thanks

**Edit: I guess I didn't ask the correct question.**

The posted code doesn't achieve what I am looking for, because the change method gets executed before the model is updated, therefore I send the incorrect/old object to the backend. Now there are a couple of ways to fix that

- Create a new variable and use it as the model
- Iterate through the list of objects and $watch every status attribute
- Another to me unkown way?

Idealy I get the new object to the change method, but I don't know how.

**Edit2: I tried to write a fiddle to make it clear, but it works there. I need to look deeper into my code, because the problem seems to be somewhere else.**

Comment: you can do like this

Comment: The main difference is that the ng-change will be not fired when the model changes programmatically, it reacts only on input value changes.

Comment: Ok, but the object only gets changed through the <select> therefore your suggestion means I need to initialize a $watch on every "status" attribute in the list? I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets clarify your problem , you have 5 dropdowns ,
with each you have 3 options a,b,c ,
and you want to do what  in a clear way?
if you mean list object in main.list by saying "update the object or already receive the correct object in the change"  then your code is ok.

Comment: With the <select> I want to change the "status" attribute of the current object. I pass the object to the "change" method, but "status" of the passed object is still the old value. I thought maybe I can't pass the object to the method and tried to read it from the list but the object in the list isn't updated either.

This means that the "change" method gets executed before the model (status) of the object is changed. But I need the updated object in the change method to update the database.

Comment: my friend , try to use  *ng-options* directive simple docs to learn is here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select and you can only set status of obj by passing both obj and obj.status together than in ng-change you set it like obj.status=obj.status[ from ng-model], i mean you only change view in your code you can set status in the controller in ng-change method