# Ionic angularjs change returned null of $scope value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My html

```
<input ng-model="query" ng-change="change(text)" type="text" placeholder="Search">
```

My js

```
  $scope.query = null;
  $scope.change = function() {
    console.log($scope.query); // null?
    $timeout(function() {
      $http.get('example.com/' + $scope.query 
        ).then(function(result){
            $scope.tracks = result.data.items;

          });
      }, 1000);
  }
```

Why is my $scope.query always got null within the change function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS: get ng-model on ng-change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669400/angular-js-get-ng-model-on-ng-change)

Comment: @RGraham so how should I solve my problem?

Comment: As per the linked question: `$scope.$watch("query", function() { $scope.change(); });` instead of using `ng-change`

Comment: @RGraham I still got undefined

Comment: Then your problem is elsewhere: http://jsfiddle.net/m5bLryou/

Comment: @RGraham I use ui-router, the console already printed $scope.query although it doesn't havent change..

Comment: Are the controller and the input with `ng-model="query"` in the same scope? Or is the input, perhaps, in a child scope? That would be another reason why the controller doesn't see the value changing.

Comment: @SunilD. it is the same scope.

Comment: @JamesLemon Little strange. It works fine here http://jsbin.com/wokeha/1/edit?html,console,output

Comment: @mohamedrias I'm confused and posted here http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-sidemnu-having-problem-to-apply-watch/19479 too..

Comment: I solved it, see here http://codepen.io/rdelafuente/pen/yiLja