# can't change assigned default value to input of type date angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input

I have the following input

```
 <input type="date" ng-model="startDateInput" ng-change="dateConvert()" />
```

And I set a default value since I call a service on the load of the page and need to pass the date as a parameter

```
$scope.startDateInput = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 1));
console.log("$scope.startDateInput" + $scope.startDateInput)
```

But later on I want this value to be updated when the user touches the date input and selects a new date on the calendar that pops up. 
The thing is, my value is not changed here.
stays the same as the default value.

```js
$scope.dateConvert = function() {
  var dateFrom = $scope.startDateInput;
  $scope.params.startDate = dateFrom;
  console.log("dateFrom " + dateFrom);
  console.log(" $scope.params.startDate  " + $scope.params.startDate);
}
```

the results of the log

> dateFrom Wed Sep 13 2017 11:22:26 GMT+0100 (Western European Summer Time)
>       tab.accountStatement.controller.js:261  $scope.params.startDate  Wed Sep 13 2017 11:22:26 GMT+0100 (Western European Summer Time)

It keeps the default value I assigned before, but why? How can I change this value?

Comment: but you don't change the date in your code, why should it be changed?

Comment: @JohnnyAW I do change when I test and pick another date

Comment: hmm, can you check, if `startDateInput` is getting updated by printing it in a span somewhere on the page? Maybe `ng-change` is being called before setting the value on the model...

Comment: `ng-change` is called _after_ the `ng-model` updates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669400/angular-js-get-ng-model-on-ng-change (the second answer is the correct one). Your code as given looks fine, it works OK too on plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/dV81tW?p=info. Where is `$scope.params` initially set in your code and does it have a `dateFrom` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$filter){
  $scope.default_date =$filter("date")(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="date" ng-model="default_date" value="{{default_date}}">
  <p>{{default_date}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```